# Nuxt 3 i18n dynamic meta title and description

Tags: internationalization, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt3

I am unable to get it properly working... well, it is working but I don't think it is the right way to do it.

Could someone please explain to me how to make my meta title and description dynamic? When I load the page now, I first see "localhost" in my tab, and shortly after that the title gets updated. I think that when Google crawls, it will take the "localhost" instead of the proper title.

I tried to get it dynamically working with this code:

````
const seoMeta = {
  title: () => metaTitle.value,
  ogTitle: () => metaTitle.value,
  description: () => i18n.t('page_meta_description', { title: metaTitle.value }),
  ogDescription: () => i18n.t('page_meta_description', { title: metaTitle.value }),
  ogImage: 'http://localhost:3000/logo_4x.png',
  twitterCard: 'summary_large_image',
};

useServerSeoMeta({ ...seoMeta });
useSeoMeta({ ...seoMeta });

const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(`https://test.com/api/de/article/${route.params.id}`)
metaTitle.value = JSON.parse(data.value).title```
````

Comment: what happens when you move the last two lines on top?

Answer (score 1):

I remember useSeoMeta being very confusing when I tried it and eventually just gave up.

Solved it for myself by using [`useHead`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head) composable instead.

```
const router = useRoute()
const itemId = router.params['id'] as string

const itemData = await $fetch(`/api/shop/item/${itemId}`)

useHead({
  title: `${itemData.title}`,
  meta: [
    {
      name: 'description',
      content: itemData.description!.short,
    },
  ],
})
```